# How can I find what folder an app is in on my iPhone using iOS 15.6.1?

Tags: folders

How can I find what folder an app is in on my iPhone using iOS 15.6.1? I am trying to find the app so that I can move it to the appropriate folder. The tips I have found in the forums are all outdated and do not work with the current operating system.

Comment: This does still work in my experience: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/346199/30895 (“Just search for it in spotlight. If there is only 1 app result it will show the folder.”)